# Shuffling method does not work as intended

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, swap

In one of my class, I wrote these lines:

```
String[] score = {"2","3","4","5"};
player = new otherClass(score);
host = new otherClasee(score);
player.shuffle();
host.shuffle()

System.out.println("player is: " + Arrays.toString(player.point));
System.out.println("host is: " + Arrays.toString(host.point));
```

And the otherClass is:

```
public class otherClass {
   String[] point;
   public otherClass(String[] something){
      point = something;
   }
   public void shuffle(){
       int ind;
       String change;
       Random rand = new Random();
       for (int i = point.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            ind = rand.nextInt(i+1);
            if (ind != i){
            change = point[i];
            point[i] = point[ind];
            point[ind] = swap;

  }
}
```

The "shuffle()" is the method inside class "otherClass" to swap elements of point[]. But the result I receive is that "player" and "host" are shuffled in the exact same way. Specifically, the "player" is shuffled first, then "host" is later. I was expecting the two shuffles to be different.

Comment: I'd be great if we saw the actual shuffle method. Also, if you have a static shuffling algorithm and you pass in the same initial values, you'll always get the same result

Comment: It sounds like your shuffle method does not use induce any randomness

Comment: You have to manually copy the contents of one array to the other, otherwise you are operating on the same array object in memory

Comment: arrays are passed by reference so you are playing with same array in whole program

Comment: `score` is a reference to an array. You can copy this reference but this doesn't copy the array. try changing `host = new otherClasee(score.clone());`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your reply. I find your method is the easiest way to make my code work.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the same array to both constructors, and shuffling it, so of course it has the same values as itself. If you want the class instances to have independent copies, give them independent copies.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same `String[]` object in both your objects "player" and "host". 
Even if they are of different classes, you give them the same object instance "score".

The solution would be to copy the "score" array.

Try

```
System.arraycopy(...)
```

You can do that in the constructor(s) or in the calling class.

Comment: Thank you. I have never really fully understood the pass-by-value concept so I couldn't detect my error there.